# Wordpress wp_update_attachment_metadata image width and height = 1?

Tags: wordpress, image

Hello Friends I used to set post thumbnail programmatically.

this is my code.

```
foreach ($csv as $key => $value) {
    $filename = "wp-content/uploads/images/".$value[8].".jpg";
    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($filename), null );
    $attachment = array(
    'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
    'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($filename)),
    'post_content' => 'this is the first project file.',
    'post_status' => 'Published'
    );
    $my_post = array(
      'post_title'    => $value[0],
      'post_content'  => $value[2],
      'post_status'   => 'publish',
      'post_author'   => 1,
      'post_type'   => 'post_staff'
    );
    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );

    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename,$post_id);
    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $filename );
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );      


    add_post_meta($post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id);
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_staff_name', $value[1] );    
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_staff_city', $value[3] );    
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_staff_postal_code', $value[4] );     
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_staff_direct_line', $value[5] );     
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_staff_fax', $value[6] );     
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_staff_email', $value[7] );    
    $tagd = array( 9 );
    wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $tagd, 'department' );   
    if($value[3] == "St. John's, NL"){
        $tagl = array( 8 );
    }else if($value[3] == "Corner Brook"){
        $tagl = array( 7 );
    }
    wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $tagl, 'location' );   
    if(set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id )){
        echo "image set";
    }
}
```

This is working fine but the imported feature image with size 1x1 width = 1 and height = 1

why it takes width and height is 1 automatically please help.

when i trying to get image using `get_the_post_thumbnail` the return image.

image is found but by default the image width = 1 and height = 1 take.

this is my code.

```
get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(), array(250,165))
```

Thank you.

Comment: Hi I am running into this problem at the moment, did you find a workaround?

Comment: @brndnmg Please Check My Answer i put answer on my question. this function is working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Function is used to import post with image in wordpress.

```
function fetch_media($file_url, $post_id) {
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-load.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
global $wpdb;

if(!$post_id) {
    return false;
}

//directory to import to    
$artDir = 'wp-content/uploads/importedmedia/';

//if the directory doesn't exist, create it 
if(!file_exists(ABSPATH.$artDir)) {
    mkdir(ABSPATH.$artDir);
}

//rename the file... alternatively, you could explode on "/" and keep the original file name
$extpop = explode(".", $file_url);
$ext = array_pop($extpop);

$new_filename = 'blogmedia-'.$post_id.".".$ext; //if your post has multiple files, you may need to add a random number to the file name to prevent overwrites

if (@fclose(@fopen($file_url, "r"))) { //make sure the file actually exists
    copy($file_url, ABSPATH.$artDir.$new_filename);

    $siteurl = get_option('siteurl');
    $file_info = getimagesize(ABSPATH.$artDir.$new_filename);

    //create an array of attachment data to insert into wp_posts table
    $artdata = array();
    $artdata = array(
        'post_author' => 1, 
        'post_date' => current_time('mysql'),
        'post_date_gmt' => current_time('mysql'),
        'post_title' => $new_filename, 
        'post_status' => 'inherit',
        'comment_status' => 'closed',
        'ping_status' => 'closed',
        'post_name' => sanitize_title_with_dashes(str_replace("_", "-", $new_filename)),                                            'post_modified' => current_time('mysql'),
        'post_modified_gmt' => current_time('mysql'),
        'post_parent' => $post_id,
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'guid' => $siteurl.'/'.$artDir.$new_filename,
        'post_mime_type' => $file_info['mime'],
        'post_excerpt' => '',
        'post_content' => ''
    );

    $uploads = wp_upload_dir();
    $save_path = $uploads['basedir'].'/importedmedia/'.$new_filename;

    //insert the database record
    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $artdata, $save_path, $post_id );

    //generate metadata and thumbnails
    if ($attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $save_path)) {
        wp_update_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $attach_data);
    }

    //optional make it the featured image of the post it's attached to
    $rows_affected = $wpdb->insert($wpdb->prefix.'postmeta', array('post_id' => $post_id, 'meta_key' => '_thumbnail_id', 'meta_value' => $attach_id));
}
else {
    return false;
}

return true;
}
```

Pass value to this function like.

```
$file_name  = 'full path of existing image';
$post_id = '1';
fetch_media($filename,$post_id);
```

Thank you.